# Schedule record deletion using Workflow/Process Builder?

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I am trying to achieve something like if my Order_date__c is older than 24 months then that order record will be deleted.

I need to store this 24 month in workflow, so that in future admin can change 24 months to whatever he wants.

How we I can build this functionality like I will count month in workflow and then i can delete that using process builder flow.

Answer (score 0):

Salesfor_dev.

Unfortunately, Process Builder will not allow you to delete records as such, you need to use `@InvocableMethod` in a class. 
There is a lot of information on this subject, you can find a good explanation and inspiration on this site:
https://automationchampion.com/tag/auto-delete-record-using-process-builder/

Try to look into **@invocable methods** and I think you will find a way to do what you want.

Regards.